# How to patch values in reactive form array in Angular, while editing input?

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

How to patch values for multiple inputs in formArray, while editing inputs values that are coming from DB? By the there are dynamic inputs implemented.

--THIS Is my formGroup with formArray--

```
 `  this.accountsForm = new FormGroup({
      'type_name': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'state': new FormControl(true, Validators.required),
      'masks': this.MaskArray,
    }); `
```

--This is FormArray--

```
`onInit() {
    this.MaskArray = new FormArray([]);
    this.MaskArray.push(
      new FormGroup({
        mask: new FormControl()
      })
    );
`
```

---This dynamic inputs creation

```
`createItem() {
    (<FormArray>this.accountsForm.get('masks')).push(
      new FormGroup({
        mask: new FormControl()
      })
    );
  }
`
```

---Here a problem appears. I tried to get values from DB and pass to inputs, it worked only for inputs with one value in array that coming from data.rows.
How to pass multiple values from data.row to mask controller of formArray--

```
`this.subs.add(this.sql.query(`Select t.Mask From Mid_s_Account_Type_Masks t Where Type_Id=${this.type_id} `).subscribe(data => {
      this.maskObj = data.rows;
      console.log(this.maskObj);
      for(var i = 0; i < this.maskObj.length ; i++){
        var j = 0;
        for(let row of this.maskObj){
          (<FormArray>this.accountsForm.controls['masks']).at(j).patchValue({
            mask: row.mask,
          });
          j++;
          console.log(row.mask);
        }
        console.log(j);
      }
    }));`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have patched formArray value in my application through `patchModelValue` method, this can be achieved with the help of `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators` package.

patchModelValue will update the value of the FormControl inside the FormGroup based on provided server JSON object or model object. For these you need to import `RxFormBuilder` in your component

```
    export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
    accountsForm : RxFormGroup

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.accountsForm  = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.group({
          masks:[
          {
            mask:''
          }]
        });
    }
 getFormArray(){
      let formarray = this.accountsForm .controls.masks as FormArray;
      return formarray.controls;
    }
    patchvalue()
    {
          this.accountsForm.patchModelValue( {
                masks: [{ mask: "xyz" }] });
    }
}
```

Please refer this example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhftk2?file=src/app/patch-complete.component.ts)